# Fatal error: Call to undefined function gregoriantojd() in docker PHP

Tags: php, docker

I have installed docker and PHP. Here is my docker file for apache module.

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN requirements="" \
    && apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y $requirements 
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

But unfortunately, I'm getting this error in one of my pages.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function gregoriantojd()

I got this [thread](http://rasyid.net/2010/04/17/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-gregoriantojd/) and found these lines,

```
cd /usr/ports/misc/php5-calendar && make install
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/php.cgi.sh stop
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/php.cgi.sh start
```

So I added 
    && docker-php-ext-install php5-calendar \

And code is like,

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN requirements="" \
    && apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y $requirements 
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install php5-calendar
```

But now I'm getting,

> error: /usr/src/php/ext/php5-calendar does not exist

when I run

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Is there any fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the specified version is not available, I am not sure if there is a dependency in your code on version but Here is the way to install calendar in PHP and verify its module.

```
FROM php:5-apache
RUN  apt-get update
RUN docker-php-ext-install calendar
```

Build
`docker build -t test .`

Run & Test

`docker run --rm  test bash -c "php -m | grep calendar"`